# jQuery toggle() method to hide table row not working

Tags: jquery

My problem is best explained by looking at [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JustJill54/Tjba6/). On load, everything is working a expected, however, when you change the dd to Dos, the only row that should show, is the dos toggle row. Currently, both Uno Toggle & Dos Toggle are being shown.

I have a constraint that I cannot use classes, so I am trying to use jQuery's :eq() selector, but I'm having issues figuring out which index number the second tr object is.

Here's my jQuery code, since it won't let me share the fiddle without showing some code.

Any help is appreciated.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
$("select[title='Numero']").closest("tr").next("tr").hide(); //commented out for debugging


 $("select[title='Numero']").change(function () {
     $("select[title='Dos Toggle']").closest("tr").closest("tr:eq(1)").toggle(); //dos toggle row
     $("select[title='Uno Toggle']").closest("tr").closest("tr:eq(2)").hide();
     //$("select[title='Uno Toggle']").closest("tr").closest("tr:eq(2)").toggle(); //this is original toggle code that didn't work.
 }); //close Numero.change()
 }); // close doc.ready
```

Comment: Is this for a SharePoint list form? From looking at the code in your fiddle, I am betting that this was copied from a SharePoint List form...

Comment: Yes @Schmalzy. This is from a SP list form

Comment: Then my answer below should work, I've used `$("nobr:contains('FIELD TITLE')").parent('h3').parent('td').parent('tr').XXXX` to target SP list form items in the past.

Comment: Also, you can check out this [JavaScript API for SharePoint](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/) to do things like this. I have never used it personally, but it may make your life a little easier if you have to do a lot of SP List manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what I came up with using the :eq() element after all of the great contributions I recieved-

```
$("select[title='Numero']").change(function () {
 $("select[title='Dos Toggle']").closest("tr").closest("tr:eq(1)").toggle(); //dos toggle row
 $("select[title='Uno Toggle']").closest("tr").closest("tr:eq(3)").toggle(); //uno toggle row
}); //close Numero.change()
```

However, I could never get this code to toggle in SharePoint the way I wanted it to...so I ended up using @Schmalzy's suggestion-

```
$("select[title='Numero']").change(function(){
            $("nobr:contains('Dos')").parent("h3").parent("td").parent("tr").toggle();      
            $("nobr:contains('Uno')").parent("h3").parent("td").parent("tr").toggle();      
}); //close
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

With what you have, you could just do:

```
 $("select[title='Numero']").change(function () {
     $(this).closest("tr").nextAll('tr').toggle();
     //Or to be more specific not to select any other trs if at all comes after these 2 you could do the below.
     //$(this).closest("tr").nextAll('tr:lt(2)').toggle();
 });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/D6LPE/)**

Comment: Because this is a SharePoint List form, this would only work if he wanted to toggle ALL items on the form. I'm betting he will have other `tr` on the form that he will not want to toggle...

Comment: @Schmalzy What do you mean by all items on the form? This wont toggle all items on the form. `closest` will select only its parent `tr`

Comment: He would most likely have many more `tr` after `Uno Toggle` and `Dos Toggle`, especially if the list has attachments enabled... Its a SharePoint thing...

Comment: @Schmalzy That is what my second option does. Did you read that, the commented one.

Comment: @Schmalzy No problem... I guessed he might have more in real world case hence added that as well.. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm betting this is for a SharePoint list form...

Here is how I have targeted rows on SharePoint forms in the past, and it works in your fiddle.... [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LAkqe/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("nobr:contains('Dos Toggle')").parent('h3').parent('td').parent('tr').toggle();

     $("select[title='Numero']").change(function () {
         $("nobr:contains('Uno Toggle')").parent('h3').parent('td').parent('tr').toggle();
         $("nobr:contains('Dos Toggle')").parent('h3').parent('td').parent('tr').toggle();
     }); //close Numero.change()

 }); // close doc.ready
```

Comment: It should be important to note that using contains does a wildcard match, so it could give undesiarble matches if the text contains the string mentioned in the selector.

Comment: Also you can replace `.parent('h3').parent('td').parent('tr')` with `.closest('tr')`

Answer (score 0):

I would start by putting css classes on the rows you're trying to show and hide. That way, you can toggle them both by just doing something like $(".numero-toggle").toggle(); inside your change function. The markup and method you're currently trying is very brittle, and if things move around or the markup changes, it will likely break.